# 12-hour clock code output "pm" has one hour less than the standard answer

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

[HDLBits 12-hour clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIj03.png)

I wrote the answer for this question, but something wrong occurred.  I can't find out where I'm wrong because the answer just tells me how many mismatches I have. Can some one tell me please?

Here are results from HDLBIts:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QWe9.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58ciz.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gciwO.png)

And here is my code:

```
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input ena,
    output pm,
    output [7:0] hh,
    output [7:0] mm,
    output [7:0] ss); 
    wire [1:0] ssc, mmc, hhc;
    
    assign ssc[0] = ss[3]&ss[0];
    counter4buenld cssl(clk, ena, reset, ssc[0], 4'h0, ss[3:0]);
    assign ssc[1] = ss[4]&ss[6]&ssc[0];
    counter4buenld cssh(clk, ena&ssc[0], reset, ssc[1], 4'h0, ss[7:4]);
    
    assign mmc[0] = mm[3]&mm[0]&ssc[1];
    counter4buenld cmml(clk, ena&ssc[1], reset, mmc[0], 4'h0, mm[3:0]);
    assign mmc[1] = mm[4]&mm[6]&mmc[0];
    counter4buenld cmmh(clk, ena&mmc[0], reset, mmc[1], 4'h0, mm[7:4]);
    
    assign hhc[0] = hh[3]&hh[0]&mmc[1];
    assign hhc[1] = hh[4]&hh[1]&mmc[1];
    counter4buenld chhl(clk, ena&mmc[1], 1'b0, reset|hhc[0]|hhc[1], {2'b00, reset, ~reset}, hh[3:0]);
    counter4buenld chhh(clk, ena&hhc[0], 1'b0, reset|hhc[1], {3'b000, reset}, hh[7:4]);
    
    reg pml;
    assign pm = pml;
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(reset) begin
            pml <= 1'b0;
        end
        else begin
        if(hh[4]&hh[0]&mmc[1]) begin
            pml <= ~pml;
        end
        else begin
            pml <= pml;
        end
        end
    end
endmodule

module counter4buenld(
    input clk,
    input ena,
    input reset,
    input load,
    input [3:0] d,
    output reg [3:0] q
);
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(reset)
            q <= 4'h0;
        else
        if(load)
            q <= d;
        else
            q <= q + ena;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HDLBits waveform snapshots do not give you enough visibility to debug your problem.  You need to create your own testbench and view the complete waveforms.

When you do so, you would see that your hour increments from 9 to 11.  It skips 10.

Your Verilog code is too difficult to understand.  Here is a simpler approach, including a trivial testbench:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input ena,
    output reg pm,
    output [7:0] hh,
    output [7:0] mm,
    output [7:0] ss
); 
    reg [7:0] hhd, mmd, ssd;

    function [7:0] bcd ([7:0] in);
        bcd[3:0] = in % 10;
        bcd[7:4] = in / 10;
    endfunction

    assign ss = bcd(ssd);
    assign mm = bcd(mmd);
    assign hh = bcd(hhd);

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            pm <= 0;
        end else if (ena && hhd==11 && mmd==59 && ssd==59) begin
            pm <= ~pm;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            ssd <= 0;
        end else if (ena) begin
            if (ssd==59) begin
                ssd <= 0;
            end else begin
                ssd <= ssd + 1;
            end
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            mmd <= 0;
        end else if (ena && ssd==59) begin
            if (mmd==59) begin
                mmd <= 0;
            end else begin
                mmd <= mmd + 1;
            end
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            hhd <= 12;
        end else if (ena && mmd==59 && ssd==59) begin
            if (hhd==12) begin
                hhd <= 1;
            end else begin
                hhd <= hhd + 1;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
   


module tb;
    bit clk;
    bit ena=1;
    bit reset=1;
    wire pm;
    wire [7:0] hh;
    wire [7:0] mm;
    wire [7:0] ss;

top_module dut (
        // Inputs:
    .clk    (clk),
    .ena    (ena),
    .reset  (reset),
        // Outputs:
    .hh     (hh),
    .mm     (mm),
    .pm     (pm),
    .ss     (ss)
);

always #5 clk++;

initial begin
    #12 reset=0;
    #5ms $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Compare MINE vs. YOURS:

[image: waves]